# Prevent python readline from taking string repr

Tags: python, newline

Suppose I have some code

```
hello = sys.stdin.readline()
```

and I type "whats up\n" (yes I actually type the \n), and then hit enter

and then

```
print(hello[:-1])
```

Which then prints "whats up\n", instead of what I want it to do, which is "whats up" and an actual newline.

What do I need to do to convert `\n` into the actual newline character? Do I have to replace it with `os.linesep`? This question also extends to the same problem of converting an inputted `\r` into a carriage return character.

Comment: isn't \n a newline?

Comment: yes, but it's being printed in the literal sense

Comment: I don't understand what you want, it is newline and printed correctly as a newline. What do you mean by "actual newline character"? If you want to remove it (along with whitespaces), call strip() sys.stdin.readline().strip()

Comment: Wait, you enter "whats up\n" and hit "Enter" or "whats up" and hit "Enter"?

Comment: inputting "whats up\n" and then printing the str[:-1] (I do this to remove the newline from hitting enter) prints "whats up\n"

Comment: But you know that entering "\n" won't be converted to new line and will be saved in string as "\\n" escaping first backslash and then adding "n"?

Comment: doh, if you input it like that, that's not newline character, that's 2 characters of \ and n. You pressed enter for newline character.

Comment: If you want to evaluate the string backslash n as a newline, you could use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but the easiest way would be `replace('\\n', '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

`\n` are the two characters `\` and `n`, they are *not* a newline. The <kbd>enter</kbd> is a newline.

You get exactly what is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to replace two charachters you have: `\` and `n` you need to call `[replace()][1]` method:

```
>>> import sys
>>> s = sys.stdin.readline()
whats\nup
>>> s
'whats\\nup\n'
>>> s.replace('\\n', '\n')
'whats\nup\n'
>>> print(s)
whats\nup

>>> print(s.replace('\\n', '\n'))
whats
up

>>>
```